# "although" vs. "even though" vs. "though"

Tags: traducción, selección-de-palabras, sinónimos, conjunciones, vocabulario

In English, there are three conjunctions that are very similar:

- although
- even though
- though

Is *aunque* the only possible translation of these to Spanish, or are there similar synonyms in Spanish as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's depends on the sentence but you can also translate them as:

- si bien.
- a pesar de (que)
- pese a (que)
- (más) bien
- No obstante
- Sin embargo

I'm probably forgetting some possibility.
All of them can be usually used as synonims but not always all of them "sound" okay.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are, although (haha although ;) ) **aunque** is the one most commonly used and the one that usually springs to mind faster.

These are your options:

> **aunque**
>
> **aún cuando**
>
> **si bien**
>
> **por más que**
>
> **no obstante**
>
> **sin embargo**
>
> **aún si**